# Exclude delimiter from regular expression

Tags: php, regex, bbcode

I'm pretty new at regular expressions.
For a string like this:

```
[quote="Username;123456]
```

I have created this regular expression:

```
%\[quote=(&quot;|&\#039;|"|\'|)([^\r\n]*?)[^;](\d+)\]%s
```

This puts out 3 matches:

- "
- Username;
- 23456

Why is `[^;]` not negating the semicolon, but instead removing one digit and how can I fix this? Thanks.

Comment: What output you expect? And why are you negating the `;`?

Comment: `[^;]` is telling the engine to **match** something that **isn't** a semi-colon, it's not 'negating' it - so it captures the first digit which meets this criteria

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `([^\r\n]*?)` can eat the `;`, so the `[^;]` is free to take a digit (because it will match anything *except* the `;`).

You probably wanted `;` (without `[^ ]`:

```
%\[quote=(&quot;|&\#039;|"|\'|)([^\r\n]*?);(\d+)\]%s
```

Comment: Thanks, now I understand it!

Answer (score 1):

I think this might be closer to what you want:

```
%\[quote=("|\')([\w]*)(?:;)(\d*)\]%s
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/7mDr9rRhcNNY4imJ)

The problem with your original pattern:

`[^;]` (for example) is telling the engine to match something that isn't a semi-colon, it's not 'negating' it - so it captures the first digit which meets this criteria due to the fact *it's not a semi-colon*